# JSON serialization in Spidermonkey

Tags: javascript, python, json, spidermonkey

I'm using `python-spidermonkey` to run JavaScript code.

In order to pass objects (instead of just strings) to Python, I'm thinking of returning a JSON string.

This seems like a common issue, so I wonder whether there are any facilities for this built into either Spidermonkey or `python-spidermonkey`.
(I do know about `uneval` but that is not meant to be used for JSON serialization - and I'd rather avoid injecting a block of JavaScript to do this.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use JSON.stringify. It's part of the ECMAScript 5 standard, and it's implemented in the current version of spidermonkey. I don't know if it's in the version used by python-spidermonkey, but if it isn't, you can get a JavaScript implementation from http://www.json.org/js.html.

Comment: I've installed the spidermonkey-bin package from the Ubuntu repositories (version info: JavaScript-C 1.7.0 2007-10-03).

However, there's no global JSON (or json) object there ("ReferenceError: JSON is not defined").

Comment: You'll need 1.8.1 to have the JSON object built-in.

Comment: Ah, that explains it - thanks! I'll look into getting (compiling?) the latest version then, and will use the JS file in the meantime.