# Can I use JSON in the spidermonkey js shell?

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

On RHEL 6.7 I installed the js-1.7 package using yum, which is handy to test out syntax before I use it for CouchDB list/view functions.

I want to use JSON.stringify() to print some objects. However, JSON isn't defined (as it would be in a browser) so I get:

```
$ js
js> JSON
typein:2: ReferenceError: JSON is not defined
```

Is it possible to use JSON in this shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 1.8.1 to have the JSON object built-in.

Read more at: [JSON serialization in Spidermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055805/json-serialization-in-spidermonkey)

*I flagged the question as duplicate, it may not be if you really need to use the 1.7 version since you'll need another solution then.*

Comment: Stupid stable redhat!